# Cannot resolve method

Tags: android, backendless

I am trying to get to show my "Uploads" folder on my Android Studio project from my Backendless files.

This is the code:

```
Backendless.Files.listing("/Uploads", "*.docs", true, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<FileInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<FileInfo> response) {
                Iterator<FileInfo> filesIterator = response.getCurrentPage().iterator();
                while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
                    FileInfo file = filesIterator.next();
                    String URL = file.getURL();
                    String publicURL = file.getPublicUrl();
                    Date createdOn = new Date(file.getCreatedOn());
                    String name = file.getName();
                }
            }
```

When I run the code I get these errors:

```
Error:(34, 38) error: cannot find symbol method getURL()
Error:(35, 44) error: cannot find symbol method getPublicUrl()
Error:(36, 51) error: cannot find symbol method getCreatedOn()
Error:(37, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getName()
Error:(28, 63) error: incompatible types: <anonymous AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<com.example.francis.classdroid.FileInfo>>> cannot be converted to AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<com.backendless.files.FileInfo>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in incorrect import of `FileInfo` class. Make sure you have imported `com.backendless.files.FileInfo`.

If you do not know what is import in Java, you can read more [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/import.html).
The imports in Java are placed at the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I have to declare the methods (in which I don't even know what to do in the method) to fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Don`t forget to accept and rate correct answers to make other people find useful ones.